# KDE Plasma - Does not give the extension in "Create New" menu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

Using KUbuntu 18.04.1

When I,

```
right click in empty space > Create New > File Type
```

The filename does not contain extension.

[image: Current Output]

I want the filename to contain extension like the following image.

[image: Expected Output]

So, far what I have checked is -

I went to `/usr/share/templates/` and checked `TextFile.desktop`. It points to `.source/TextFile.txt`

`/usr/share/templates/.source/TextFile.txt`

Is a plain text file with extension. So, as far my understanding the new file should come with an extension.

After further investigation, I found that Although, created LibreOffice files automagically open in Libreoffice, these do not have extensions either.

Comment: Apparently Kubuntu doesn't use the `~/Templates` folder that other (GNOME) distros use. I was looking at Xubuntu 18.04 and that has exactly what you want. And most of the references I found on the topic were for kde4. Let's hope someone comes along with a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**KDE and the XDG templates**

A bug report: Bug 191632 - It should be easier to add a template to "Create New..." menu (e.g. look into ~/Templates) - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191632

...and the fix: [KIO] Add support for XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR in KNewFileMenu - https://cgit.kde.org/kio.git/commit/?id=de5ab5e74b4c5a6ce482af8ded7b7b60966d20bb

**Older versions**

The KDE4 and the KF5 (pre the kio fix) are using the /usr/share/templates/ and the $HOME/.local/share/templates/.

**Example**

Adding the 'File Text.txt' option to the Dolphin and the Plasma 'Create New' context menus.

Making $HOME/.local/share/templates/TextFile2.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Text File.txt

Comment=Enter text filename:

Type=Link
URL=.source/TextFile2.txt
Icon=text-plain
```

and

Copying the /usr/share/templates/.source/TextFile.txt to the $HOME/.local/share/templates/.source/TextFile2.txt. It is an empty file.

[image]

Both the Dolphin and the Plasma have new 'Create New' context menus:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your second link does not work anymore